# Find docs that have macros in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, macros

I'm trying to build a tool in C# that will trawl through a list of documents, and produce a list that have macros.  I can't find a property that will let me identify such documents though.
Is there a way I can force a document to run all it's macros? I could then catch the ones that fail as they have no macros and eliminate them.
The documents are either Word/Excel 2002 or 2007 format.

Thanks.

Comment: include the code that you are currently attempting, which opens a document file. It is needed, to know what library/classes you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Document.HasVBProject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.hasvbproject%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property (under the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace) will tell you whether a document has any macros.